# Lessen the indent in a multi-level list

Tags: html, css, html-lists, indentation

I have a navigation pane in my website that I am building, and I have multiple levels of navigation. Is there any way for me to make the indent in the second level of my navigation pane smaller?

this is the important part of my code:

```css
<style>
        div.sidebarOne {
         background-color: rgba(64, 224, 208, 0.50); 
         position: absolute;
         top: 0; 
         bottom: -3000px; 
         left: 1px;
         width: 270px;
         margin: 0 auto;
         clear: all;
         padding-left: 5px;
        }
        li  {
         color: goldenrod;
         size: 20px;
         font-family: Bellota-Light;
         word-spacing: 5px;
        }
        li.sidebar  {
         color: darkred;
         size: 20px;
         font-family: Bellota-Light;
         word-spacing: 5px;
        }
</style>
```

```html
<aside>
 <div class="sidebarOne"> <!-- the sidebar on the right -->
<h1 format="title"> Contents </h1>
  <ul>
   <li class="sidebar">Inquiry and Analysis</li>
    <ul>
     <li class="sidebar"><a href="../Other Pages/Page_2_mindmap.html"> My MindMaps </a> </li>
     <li class="sidebar"><a href="../Other Pages/Page_3_narrowedmindmap.html"> My Research Topic </a> </li>
     <li class="sidebar"><a href="../Other Pages/Page_4_questions.html">Some Questions</a> </li>
     <li class="sidebar"><a href="../Other Pages/Page_5_pre-existingsites.html">Analysis of other websites</a> </li>
     <li class="sidebar"><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
   <li class="sidebar">Developing Ideas</li>
   <li class="sidebar">Creating a Solution</li>
   <li class="sidebar">Evaluating</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</aside>
```

The sidebar is in the `<div class="sidebar.one">` 
I just want to add that I'd rather not change it to a `nav` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists have built in padding by default so it's generally a good idea to reset these with:

```
ul {
  padding:0;
}
```

Then apply whatever padding you require directly. Here I've removed it comepletely...

```css
<style> div.sidebarOne {
  background-color: rgba(64, 224, 208, 0.50);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: -3000px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 270px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: all;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  color: goldenrod;
  size: 20px;
  font-family: Bellota-Light;
  word-spacing: 5px;
}
li.sidebar {
  color: darkred;
  size: 20px;
  font-family: Bellota-Light;
  word-spacing: 5px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="sidebarOne">
    <!-- the sidebar on the right -->
    <h1 format="title"> Contents </h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="sidebar">Inquiry and Analysis</li>
      <ul>
        <li class="sidebar"><a href="../Other Pages/Page_2_mindmap.html"> My MindMaps </a> 
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar"><a href="../Other Pages/Page_3_narrowedmindmap.html"> My Research Topic </a> 
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar"><a href="../Other Pages/Page_4_questions.html">Some Questions</a> 
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar"><a href="../Other Pages/Page_5_pre-existingsites.html">Analysis of other websites</a> 
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar"><a href="../index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <li class="sidebar">Developing Ideas</li>
      <li class="sidebar">Creating a Solution</li>
      <li class="sidebar">Evaluating</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

When nesting a `<ul>` you need to keep it with the parent `<li>`.

```
<li>Some Text
    <ul>
        <li>Some Other Text</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

```css
.sidebar ul {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

As a side note, be careful when using default margin and padding that browsers apply, they're not always the same. Use a [reset stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or a use an existing boilerplate CSS like [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) to provide basic styling for form elements, grid etc.